Questions regarding converting / merging a 'pre' docker-compose bash script into one docker-compose file
I have inhereted a project that loads a preload.sh script before running the docker-compose.yml file.
The preload.sh script is as follows;
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker network create traefik-work

docker run -d --name traefik \
    -p 80:80 \
    -p 443:443 \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    -v $PWD/traefik/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    --network=traefik-work \
    traefik:latest

The reason they wanted to do this was to make sure that the traefik network was running before booting any containers that use the traefik-work network.
Here is the docker-compose.yml being used.
services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: mynginx
    networks:
      - legacy-work
      - traefik-work
    depends_on:
      - php
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.mynginx.rule=Host(`mynginx.local`) || Host(`anotherservice.local`)
      - traefik.http.routers.mynginx.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-work
    environment:
      - HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect

  nginx-seperate:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: mynginx-seperate
    networks:
      - legacy-work
      - traefik-work
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.mynginxseperate.rule=Host(`api.seperate.local`)
      - traefik.http.routers.mynginxseperate.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-work
    environment:
      - HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect

  php:
    container_name: myphp
    networks:
      - legacy-work
      - traefik-work
    build:
      context: .
      target: local
    command: ["/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm", "-F", "-R"]
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    expose:
      - "9000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    links:
      - mysql:db-host
    env_file:
      - ".env"

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.35
    container_name: mymysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    networks:
      - legacy-work
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydatabase
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysql

  node:
    image: node:10.17.0-alpine
    container_name: mynode
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    container_name: mymailhog
    networks:
      - legacy-work
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"

volumes:
  db-volume:

networks:
  legacy-work:
    name: legacy-work
  traefik-work:
    external: true
    name: traefik-work

I am wondering though if its pointless having this preload.sh script and just bring the Traefik container into the docker-compose.yml making it much cleaner. I have put together the following and im wondering if I could get some eyes on to see if anything could be improved;
I changed the 'network' to bridge instead of external, i included a traefik block with everything that was in the prescript, the only thing im unsure about is the ports in the traefik container arent in the command portion, but im not sure if thats how it works, and i have added the traefik container to the depends_on section to all services that uses the traefik-work network .... That would make sure the traefik container is running before any of the others are booted right? I added a networks block to the traefik container, but im not sure if this is the corrent way of doing it ... Can anyone see if I can improve on this?
services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - traefik-work
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:80"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: mynginx
    networks:
      - legacy-work
      - traefik-work
    depends_on:
      - traefik
      - php
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.mynginx.rule=Host(`mynginx.local`) || Host(`anotherservice.local`)
      - traefik.http.routers.mynginx.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-work
    environment:
      - HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect

  nginx-seperate:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: mynginx-seperate
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    networks:
      - legacy-work
      - traefik-work
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.mynginxseperate.rule=Host(`api.seperate.local`)
      - traefik.http.routers.mynginxseperate.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-work
    environment:
      - HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect

  php:
    container_name: myphp
    networks:
      - legacy-work
      - traefik-work
    build:
      context: .
      target: local
    command: ["/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm", "-F", "-R"]
    depends_on:
      - traefik
      - mysql
    expose:
      - "9000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    links:
      - mysql:db-host
    env_file:
      - ".env"

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.35
    container_name: mymysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    networks:
      - legacy-work
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydatabase
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysql

  node:
    image: node:10.17.0-alpine
    container_name: mynode
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    container_name: mymailhog
    networks:
      - legacy-work
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"

volumes:
  db-volume:

networks:
  legacy-work:
    name: legacy-work
  traefik-work:
    driver: bridge
    name: traefik-work

Im sorry about the long question, im trying to learn the best way it can. Thank you.

Is there a specific problem you're running into?  Your overall approach seems fine, and I agree that there's not an obvious reason to run that one container outside of Compose.  Your Compose setup is a little different from the docker run setup (it looks like you're passing configuration options via command: arguments rather than a config file) but I'm guessing you're aware of this already.

@DavidMaze ... I want to cut down on the amount of config files, the code hasnt been audited in MANY years and i just want to streamline it and it seems this preload script is completely pointless considering the depends_on argument ... But i just want to make sure that im not stuffing anything up with the way im moving the docker run command into the actual docker-compose file ... Just wanted to get some eyes to see if im missing anything or i could improve anything
